# Unable to pass data from parent window to child window of addon

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, polymer

I have a Polymer application wherein we need to spawn a new tab with a JSON data which the tab sends to the backed and gets a rendered HTML as a response.

The approach I took was to set a variable in the parent window as:

```
window.previewJSON = some_json; //stringified json
```

followed by:

```
window.open("/preview.html");
```

to open a the preview file having the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Preview</title>
  <script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
  (function () {
    var json = window.opener !== null ? window.opener.previewJSON : window.parent.previewJSON;
    window.previewJSON = json;

    if (!window.sessionStorage.getItem("page_json"))
      window.sessionStorage.setItem("page_json", json);

    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/render/page',
      dataType: 'text',
      type: 'post',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: window.sessionStorage.getItem("page_json"),
      success: function (data) {
        $('#content').html(data);
      },
      error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });
  }).call(this);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The preview tab is now able to get the JSON from the parent and the AJAX render works perfectly. Now I'm using a chrome plugin Responsive Web Design Tester found [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/responsive-web-design-tes/objclahbaimlfnbjdeobicmmlnbhamkg) (its a business requirement to use this) to test the preview in a responsive view. This tool spawns a new window with the current URL and attempts to load the content. Now I need to pass the JSON data along to that as well.

What I noticed is that, in the tab that I opened earlier the data is available in the **window.opener.previewJSON**, whereas in the window opened by the tool its in **window.opener** is null and **window.parent.previewJSON** is exists but is undefined.

The code

```
var json = window.opener !== null ? window.opener.previewJSON : window.parent.previewJSON;
window.previewJSON = json;
```

is for this reason.

Weirdly if I write window.parent.previewJSON as some constant like "Hello" its available in the plugin window, but if I use the variable json its undefined for some reason.

I'm unable figure out why this might be happening. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: is `some_json` an object or a string? What makes you think that `window.parent.previewJSON` exists if it's undefined (It could be, but how did you test this)? and lastly, please explain your statement about the "Hello" constant, or better yet, show the code for both "pages" (only relevant parts please) -> [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you can

Comment: some_json is a string. And I tested it out on the inspector for the existence of the object, and the key is present but the value is undefined. About the constant, when i write window.parent.previewJSON = "Hello", then the inspector in the plugin window shows window.parent.previewJSON as "Hello". The code is common in the tab as well as the plugin window.